# Locally Insert Image not working on Jupyter NoteBook

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

When i use pyhon code to insert image on jupyter notebook then it can worked but when i want to insert it locally using ![](11.1 6-step-ml-framework.png) then it is not working just show it as a lebel. Note i change it to markdown

[image]

[image]

Comment: The cell being markdown is not demonstrated here and seem dubious. It looks like raw code because it isn't showing color highlighting good markdown would have colors for the text specifying an embedded image. Did you hit shift-enter on the markdown cell? Maybe add a header to prove the highlighting is working or not? Try a new notebook? Have you tried other images? Have you shut this down and started Jupyter up again? Minor aside: This has nothing to do with machine-learning and so not really pertinent as a tag

Comment: If it is good markdown and not working, you'd need to post versions of Jupyter Notebook so you can see if anyone already reported it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly drag and drop the image in the MD cell.
But sometimes it still doesn't work and if you are working on a Virtual Machine like Kaggle, the kernel won't commit if the notebook exceeds the 1Mb limit
I prefer adding images from the drive

Suppose you have an image on a drive which you'd like to upload, copy its link which might look like this

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/`1MpcRUdJ4msUCIuhwl3s679Mjuv4LrcR2`/view?usp=drive_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/%601MpcRUdJ4msUCIuhwl3s679Mjuv4LrcR2%60/view?usp=drive_link)

find such portion and replace in the following tag

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1MpcRUdJ4msUCIuhwl3s679Mjuv4LrcR2" width="800"/>
</p>
```

In MD it will return the following

[image]